# (Interpretation of) Maximum cable length on Ethernet

Tags: cable

As far as I understand the max. cable length applies to the length between devices (e.g. switches, repeaters etc.). [Here](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7483/minimum-ethernet-cable-length) I found the following citation:

> For 10BASE-T, Clause 14.1.1.1 Medium Attachment Unit (MAU) explicitly
> states "Provides for operating over 0 m to at least 100 m of twisted
> pair without the use of a repeater."

I'm not too familiar with repeaters in detail, but according to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/networking/comments/2fwp73/can_i_use_a_switch_as_a_repeater/) a switch should work as well. So the following connection:

```
switch -> 5m stranded to patch panel -> 90m solid-core to next patch panel -> 5m stranded to switch
```

will have a length of 100m in total, so it's still within the specs, right? And if the max. lenght only applies to devices this should work:

```
Overview:
switch1       <--100mTotal-->       switch2       <--100mTotal-->       switch3

Detailed:
switch -5m-> patch-90m-> patch-5m -> switch -5m-> patch -90m-> patch-5m -> switch
```

Comment: Your lengths are incorrect for the horizontal (maximum 90 meters) and patch cables (5 meters on each end).

Comment: See the answer to the above linked question.

Comment: By the way, there are many different ethernet standards, and the maximum cable lengths vary by standard. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1344285/502557) about different lengths for the different standards.

Comment: @RonMaupin I think I need to rephrase the question altogether. But I'll have a look at the links first. Meanwhile, aren't 90m +5m on each interchangeable with 98m +1m at each end?

Comment: No, that is explained in the linked answers.

Comment: As explained in the answers I linked, the horizontal cable is limited to 90 meters, and you can have up to 10 meters of patch cable split between the two ends. The full channel is limited to 100 meters, but that is between the two types of cabling. Your 98 meter horizontal cable is out of specifications, and it will fail the category test suite.

Comment: @RonMaupin Although I understand the formal test fail, I don't understand why this shouldn't work, but I changed (the first part of) the question to avoid this problem. Is this better? I decided to post the second part in a separate question - less confusion...